# Angularjs and data_ng_value

Tags: angularjs

Simple, i have to inputs: name and username

As user enters name, username is being filled with those information.

So, name input has `data_ng_model = "formData.name"`
username has `data_ng_model = "formData.username"` and `data_ng_value = "formData.name"`

And generally it works, but when user doesn't enter anything in `username` input by his own, then `formData.username` is null.

How to fix that?

Comment: can u add screenshot of ur error

Answer (score 0):

Just set the value to an empty string, either in your controller with:

```
$scope.formData = { name: ''}
```

Or on the element itself:

```
<input ng-model="name" ng-init="name=''" />
```